# Question about structures of $SO(3)$ and the elements in $SO(3)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

Given a vector $v$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\mathbb{R}_v^2$ be the orthogonal complement to $\mathbb{R}v$. Then $\mathbb{R}_v^2$ has a positive orientation that obeys the right hand rule.

Let $\theta$ be any angle. Then we can take $\mathbb{R}_v^2$ along the axis $\mathbb{R}_v$. A choice of $v$ and $\theta$ then gives all the element in $SO(3)$.

Here I'm not sure why we can have such choice of $v$. Also, I'm not sure how this provides all the elements in $SO(3)$.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: $v$ is given, so you don't have to prove it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is that you are in an odd-dimensional vector space: Any matrix $A\in SO(3)$ (or to be more general $A\in\mathbb{R}^{(2n+1)\times (2n+1)}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$) has at least one real eigenvalue, since its characteristic polynomial has odd degree (and thus a real zero). More precisely, one of these real eigenvalues is $1$ due to the condition $\det A=1$.

The subspace $\mathbb{R}_v$ spanned by a corresponding eigenvector $v\in\mathbb{R}^3$ is then fixed under $A$, i.e. is invariant under rotation, and so $A$ is completely determined by its action on $\mathbb{R}_v^2$, which is given by a rotation around some angle $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$.

Formally, this means that each matrix in $SO(3)$ is conjugate to a matrix of the form
$$\left(\begin{matrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta &0\\ \sin\theta&\cos\theta&0\\0&0& 1\end{matrix}\right).$$

Comment: Why do we know that the subspace $\mathbb{R}_v$ is invariant under rotation from the fact that one of the eigenvalues is 1? Thanks!

Comment: @Korn That's what $v$ being an eigenvector means. Eigenvectors are vectors that are simply scaled by the transformation $v\mapsto \lambda v$ so the line containing them is preserved (since $\lambda =1$ here each point in the line is fixed and not just the line itself)

Comment: @Korn As Callum said, this invariance just comes from the definition of eigenvalues/ eigenvectors: $Av = \lambda v$ means that $v$ is stretched by the factor $\lambda$ when $A$ is applied. So if one only considers the linear span $\langle v\rangle := \mathbb{R}_v := \{t v : t\in\mathbb{R}\}\subset\mathbb{R}^3$,
this subspace stays invariant under $A$, since every vector $w\in\mathbb{R}_v$ can be written as $w = tv$ for some $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and thus $Aw = t(Av) = (t\lambda)v\in\mathbb{R}_v$.